# net maui hide keyboard when flyoutpage is shown

Tags: .net, maui, flyout

When an entry has focus and the keyboard is shown, when i then open the flyoutpage by clicking the burger icon on the top left, the keyboard remains open.

I would like the keyboard to close when i open the flyoutpage.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the keyboard to close when i open the flyoutpage.

Suppose the Entry exists in the `FlyoutPageItem: Page1` as below:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                        x:FieldModifier="public"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectedItem="null">
      <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:FlyoutPageItem}">

                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Page1"
                                      IconSource="hamburger_icon.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:Page1}" />
```

You can add [HideSoftInputOnTapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.contentpage.hidesoftinputontapped#microsoft-maui-controls-contentpage-hidesoftinputontapped) in `Page 1` in `XAML` like below which indicates whether tapping anywhere on the page will cause the soft input keyboard to hide if it's visible. Before clicking the burger icon on the top left, you can tap anywhere on the `Page 1` which will hide the keyboard per your requirement. Lastly, this is a `.NET 8` newly added feature so make sure your app is `.NET 8` based.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppFlyoutNavigation.Page1"
             
             HideSoftInputOnTapped="True"
             Title="Page1 ">
```